# wrap a layout with textviews

Tags: android, layout

I have a layout that looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
<!--aligned parent top-->
</<RelativeLayout>
<FlowLayout>
<!--Should fill remaining space-->
</FlowLayout>
<RelativeLayout>
<!--aligned parent bottom-->
</<RelativeLayout>
```

I used [FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout) to show a list of textviews(It may contain 10-15 textviews). So, based on available empty screen space, I want to show number of textviews. For example, if there are 15 textviews to be shown there and there is space for 10 textviews in a large screen, I want to show 9 textviews and show "+6" in the last textview. In a small screen space may be available only for 5 textviews, in that i want to show 4 textviews with "+11" in the last textview. For clear understanding, here is the screenshot. As you can see, actual number of textviews to be displayed are 5. but 2 are displayed, and +3 is added. Similarly, based on screen space available, I want to add number of textviews in the layout.

How can this be achieved programmatically?

[image]

Comment: can you able to get how many textviews are visible in your FlowLayout ?

Comment: or otherwise you will put <FlowLayout> in scrollview. so you dont have to count.

Comment: I don't want to scroll Flow layout. As you can see in the screenshot above, I want to display as number of textviews as the screen can, and show "+remaining" at the end.

Comment: If it is a larger screen, I want to show all the 5 textviews instead of "+3" as in the screenshot.

Comment: this is a clear call for a custom layout. measuring the available views, trying to get as many as possible to fit in it, and display an overflow view for the rest. you will probably not get any good results with just using linear layouts or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the textviews in a loop, adding each one separately in a new OnPreDrawListener. After each one is added, check if it exceeds the space on the row, and if so remove it and add the counter. If it still exceeds the row, remove one more and increase the counter.

The key is to test each in a separate OnPreDrawListener, so it all happens before the view is shown, but **after** the view has had its layout and size calculated.

Answer (score 9):

Try programmatically adding TextViews to a linearLayout in a for loop in which after adding each textView, get remaining width available (Can be calculated using [ScreenWidth-(sum of added textviews width + [no.of textviews * margin/padding for each])]*)

If width is less than a certain minimum (say you need 100px minimum for each textview) then break the loop and add the count indicator text.

I can think of below code, it might not be precise but just to show you what Im thinking of

```
int screenWidth = getScreenWidth();
    int currentWidth=0;
    int minimumWidthForAChildWithOffset = 100;//offset should include width of indicator 
    int childCount = 10;
    int paddingForEachChild = 15;
    for (int i = 0; i <childCount; i++) {
        TextView label= getChildView();
        parent.addView(label, i);
        currentWidth += parent.getChildAt(i).getWidth() + paddingForEachChild;
        if(i!=childCount-1/*ignore if this is the last item*/ && screenWidth-currentWidth<=minimumWidthForAChildWithOffset){
            //add indicator label to layout here
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "say you need 100px minimum for each textview"... Textview's width isn't fixed. all texts are not of same length. Texts come from a REST service. So if there are three texts which are 2-3 characters long and then the 4th one comes which is 20 characters long?

Answer (score 2):

If I had to implement something like you described, I would try to fork/subclass FlowLayout and update its `onMeasure` and `onLayout` methods.

Here's the FlowLayout: https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout/blob/develop/FlowLayout/src/main/java/com/wefika/flowlayout/FlowLayout.java

1) First step is to limit height of FlowLayout in `onMeasure`. Also, It might be enough to do something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" ... >
    <RelativeLayout ... />    
    <FlowLayout android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" ... />        
    <RelativeLayout ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

2) Second step is to update `onLayout`, so it stops adding lines and line views when max height is reached, then add your view which displays number of hidden views